# Is it common use to save php code in a database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a game achievement system on my site. The goal is to have multiple achievements available for the user to achieve. In order to check if the user has completed an achievement, i need some kind of check whether a variable has reached a certain level(e.g. amount of games played >= 5).

I have a field in the database, "complete_code", which contains a code that returns true when the achievement was completed(e.g. 5 games played) and false otherwise. I execute this code with the php eval function.

Is it common practice to save code in a database, or is this a no go?

Comment: Generally not a good idea, especially if the only option to execute it is eval with all its problems (such as failing to handle errors in the code cleanly)

Comment: You can better use MySQL functions for that. Your code (logic) should be seperated from your data.

Comment: i see no reason for code to be stored in the db based on your description.

Comment: Well, I found some similar uses in Joomla (or Virtuemart, I don't remember, it was storing some kind of a formatting template, allowing php too, if I remember correctly), but having something mutable per user actions allowing for just about anything on a site seems to be "shaky" at least...

Comment: you would normally just store the variables in the DB